# preg_match name of input field inside form

Tags: php, forms, preg-match

Sorry, i spent like 2 hours trying to preg_match this form

```
<form class="form-search" method="post" action="/index.php">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input id="address_box" type="text" class="form-control" name="x" value="" onfocus="this.select()" />
  </div>
<span class="btn btn-s btn-caps"><input type="submit" value="start" /></span>
</form>
```

To:

```
Preg_match:

START = <form

WHERE action CONTAIN /index.php
EX: action="/index.php" or action="http://whatever.com/index.php"

FIND name="[A-Za-z]{1}"

END = </form>

Then Output the [A-Za-z]{1} Match (Should get x)
```

How can i do it correctly please?

Thanks.

Comment: What kind of error are you getting? Can you give more details?

Comment: @mjuarez i tried a lot of regex, but nothing worked out like i want.

Comment: What exectly are you trying to match? [a-zA-Z]{1} matches at least 1 or more chars.

Comment: @AmitThakur match name="*" inside the form where action contain "/index.php" so,  the output of [a-zA-Z]{1} will be x

Comment: Okay then you need this


 if(preg_match("/[a-zA-Z]{1}/i",$_POST["x"]))
{echo "valid input";}
else

{echo "invalid input";}

Comment: No, i need to preg_match it as html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this regex should do the job:

```
$regex = '/<form.*(?<=action=\")?\/index.php\">.*(?<=name=\")([A-Za-z]{1})(?=\").*?<\/form>/s';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$pat = /\/index.php\">.*?form-control\".*(?<=name=\")([A-Za-z]{1})(?=\")/s

$sub = '<form class="form-search" method="post" action="/index.php">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input id="address_box" type="text" class="form-control" name="x" value="" onfocus="this.select()" />
  </div>
<span class="btn btn-s btn-caps"><input type="submit" value="start" /></span>
</form>';

preg_match($pat,$sub,$match);


to echo mateched use echo $match[1];
```