# preg_match and get name of input field in matched form

Tags: php, forms, preg-match

Ok, i have 2 forms like this:

```
$sub = '

Some text....
<form class="form-search" method="post" action="/index.php">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input id="address_box" type="text" class="form-control" name="x" value="" onfocus="this.select()" />
  </div>
<span class="btn btn-s btn-caps"><input type="submit" value="start" /></span>
</form>
Some text....
<form class="form-search" method="post" action="/home.php">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input id="address_box" type="text" class="form-control" name="y" value="" onfocus="this.select()" />
  </div>
<span class="btn btn-s btn-caps"><input type="submit" value="start" /></span>
</form>
Some text....
';
```

I want to:

```
Preg_match:

START = <form

WHERE action CONTAIN /index.php
EX: action="/index.php" or action="http://whatever.com/index.php"

FIND name="[A-Za-z]{1}"

END = </form>

Then Output the [A-Za-z]{1} Match
```

Now here is my code:

```
$pat = '/<form.*(?<=action=\")?\/index.php\">.*(?<=name=\")([A-Za-z]{1})(?=\").*?<\/form>/s';
preg_match($pat,$sub,$match);
print_r($match[1]);
```

This should select the first form and output = x

But i'm getting output = y (the last one)

My regex works correctly if i have 1 form only, but if i have 2 forms or more, it always skip all and match the last one and that's completely wrong.

What is wrong please?

Thanks.

Comment: dom + xpath wouldn't be better?

Comment: add an `?` to your `.*` to make the expression ungready

Comment: possible duplicate of [preg\_match name of input field inside form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29052172/preg-match-name-of-input-field-inside-form)

Comment: @JESUISCHARLIE i posted that question too and it's not the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change your regex to something like this:

```
$pat = '~<form[^>]+action="[^"]*/(?:index.php)"[^>]*>(?!.*<form).*name="([a-zA-Z]{1})".*?</form>~s';
preg_match($pat,$sub,$match);
print_r($match[1]);
```

Comment: thank you, just a small thing, this going to get whatever inside name="" i need it where name="[A-Za-z]{1}" only

Comment: action must contain /index.php it can be action="/index.php" or action="http://whatever.com/index.php" but it can't be action="/index.php?s=w" (should have nothing after /index.php)

Comment: Philipp, thanks for your help, i  tested the new expression with http://pastebin.com/Zw2VXV55 the correct output is x however i'm getting y , could you check please?

Comment: ok.. I see - just updated the expression and added an negative lookahead: https://regex101.com/r/fV2yJ7/2

Comment: looks like it's really hard to get it work exactly like i want, the new expression doesn't match the original string of this question, if possible, just please take a last look, i'm going to accept this answer anyway, thank you.